# Is there a typo in the XGBoost example in the paper?

Tags: xgboost

I am reading the [XGBoost paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf) and I found this example below in the paper to calculate the quality tree structure:

[image]

To calculate the quality tree structure, we use the following formula:

[image]

**My question, forgetting 0.5 before the summation in the example, is it a typo in the paper?**